# converting space separated file into csv format in linux

Tags: shell, csv, awk

I have a file that contain data in the format

```
                             2 Mar 1 1234 141.98.80.59
                             1 Mar 1 1234 171.239.249.233
                             5 Mar 1 admin 116.110.119.156
                             4 Mar 1 admin1 177.154.8.15
                             2 Mar 1 admin 141.98.80.63
                             2 Mar 1 Admin 141.98.80.63
```

i tried this command to convert into csv format but it is giving me the output with extra (,) in the front

**cat data.sql | tr -s '[:blank:]' ',' > data1.csv**

```
      ,2,Mar,1,1234,141.98.80.59
      ,1,Mar,1,1234,171.239.249.233
      ,5,Mar,1,admin,116.110.119.156
      ,4,Mar,1,admin1,177.154.8.15
      ,2,Mar,1,admin,141.98.80.63
      ,2,Mar,1,Admin,141.98.80.63
```

In my file there is 6 character space is there in-front on every record

how can i remove extra comma from the front

Comment: You want to keep the leading spaces?

Comment: Can you show your expected output in question?

Answer (score 3):

*how [to] remove extra comma from the front* using awk:

```
$ awk -v OFS=, '{$1=$1}1' file
```

Output:

```
2,Mar,1,1234,141.98.80.59
1,Mar,1,1234,171.239.249.233
5,Mar,1,admin,116.110.119.156
...
```

Output with [@EdMorton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66456419/converting-space-separated-file-into-csv-format-in-linux/66456730?noredirect=1#comment117494865_66456730)'s version proposed in comments:

```
      2,Mar,1,1234,141.98.80.59
      1,Mar,1,1234,171.239.249.233
      5,Mar,1,admin,116.110.119.156
      ...
```

Comment: Or `awk -v OFS=',' '{$1="      "$1}1' file` if the OP really does want 6 leading blank chars on every line.

Answer (score 1):

The improved version of your current method is:

```
cat data.sql | sed -E -e 's/^[[:blank:]]+//g' -e 's/[[:blank:]]+/,/g' > data1.csv
```

But do be aware that replacing spaces/commas isnt a real way of changing this format into a CSV. If there are/were any commas and/or spaces present in the actual data this approach would fail.

The fact that your example source file has the `.sql` extension suggests that perhaps you get this file by exporting a database, and have already stripped parts of the file away with other `tr` statements ? If that is the case, a better approach would be to export to CSV (or another format) directly

edit: Made `sed` statement more portable as recommended by per Quasímodo in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Miller](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) is

```
mlr --n2c -N remove-empty-columns ./input.txt >./output.txt
```

The output will be

```
2,Mar,1,1234,141.98.80.59
1,Mar,1,1234,171.239.249.233
5,Mar,1,admin,116.110.119.156
4,Mar,1,admin1,177.154.8.15
2,Mar,1,admin,141.98.80.63
2,Mar,1,Admin,141.98.80.63
```